# Why do I get a "HTTP Status 400 - Illegal Request Body" for this POST?

Tags: xml, http

```
POST http://anyservice.com/my/servlet/interface/v1/book/events  
Content-Type: application/xml  
Accept: application/xml  
Authorization: Basic cXRE456ggz  

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CreateEvent>
  <serviceType>ABC</serviceType>
  <Version>2&#xD;</Version>
  <data>xyz</data>
</CreateEvent>
```

I'm guessing that CRLF i.e. `#xD;` is illegal in the middle of an HTTP BODY,
but I can't find a reference in any RFC.

Why do I get a "HTTP Status 400 - Illegal Request Body" for this POST ?

Comment: Maybe because ampersand is illegal in XML.

Comment: Can you please provide an RFC reference ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not indicating that the request body is not compliant with HTTP, it is indicating that the request is not compliant with the application. Arguably 400 is the wrong response code in this situation, but at the same time I have been known to use it in this situation myself.

Really (IMHO) there should be a separate response code for use when the request does not comply with the overlying application, and 400 should be reserved for ([as RFC2616 states](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1)) "malformed syntax" at the HTTP protocol level. But there isn't, so 400 makes the most sense.

My guess as to why it borks at your input is because you have an XML syntax error - the opening `<CreateEvent>` tag is missing it's closing `>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><CreateEvent<serviceType>ABC</serviceType>...
                                                                  ^^ Missing >
```

It's also possible that they don't like the carriage return, it which case just strip it out.

Comment: sorry, missing &gt; was a typo, and app is internal, not google.

I guess the principle remains the same, that it is valid to have ampersandxD; in the POST body.

Comment: There is no *content* that is invalid in the request body. Unless you are using a method that does not permit a body, or the content-type does not match the content. Maybe try a content-type of `text/xml`? Also your request does not appear to include a `Host:` or `Content-Length:` header, or the HTTP version, and the URI is a full URL - all of which are RFC violations (the last one isn't if you are using a proxy server, and `Content-Length:` is mandatory because you are using the POST method) - you say the app is internal, do you control the source code?